# Display a certain value if subquery's resultset column value is NULL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, null, case

I am trying to display a value of **'No'** if a returned column's value is `NULL`
I am using a **subquery** to select the column from another table in the database.

I already tried `IS NULL` but can't get the result I want.

```
SELECT r.*,
CASE (SELECT isComplete FROM admission_mt WHERE registration_id = 1) 
WHEN NULL THEN 'No' END AS isAdmissionComplete
FROM registration_mt r
WHERE r.schoolyear_yearfrom = 2018;
```

What I get for isAdmissionComplete column is `NULL` instead of a **'No'**

[image]

I need to be able to display a value so that when I do something like
`resultSet.getString("isAdmissionComplete")` then I'll get at least some value instead of a `NULL` value which may result in `NULLPointerException` in Java

Thank you.

Comment: why are your writing complete sql here `(SELECT isComplete FROM admission_mt WHERE r.registration_id = 1)` ? and what does it return ?

Comment: Read up on coalesce and ifnull.

Comment: @Ravi sorry, it's actually registration_id = 1 without the " r ". When I run that code, it only displays the column name without any value, no NULL, just empty or ''

Comment: @p3ace not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: Agree with Ravi I can't see what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: `SELECT isComplete FROM admission_mt WHERE r.registration_id = 1` should be  `SELECT isComplete FROM admission_mt a where r.registration = a.registration_id`.   It makes no sense to select admission_mt for registration_id 1 for all rows of registration_mt.

Comment: Thanks everyone. While I was checking your comments and recommendation, I just realized what I'm doing wrong. The admission_mt table doesn't have any record matching the registration_mt table. I had to do a LEFT JOIN with a CASE WHEN.

Comment: Just for your info, you are supposed to accept and upvote correct answer and upvote other helpful answer. This expects community from everyone. Read this meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

Try

`WHEN IS NULL THEN`

Note the added `IS`

Answer (score 1):

> Select r.*, Case when isAdmissionComplete is null then 'No' when
>   isAdmissionComplete is not null then 'Yes' end as
>   "isAdmissionComplete" FROM registration_mt r WHERE
>   r.schoolyear_yearfrom = 2018;

[Result Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSTfG.png)

Result text

date_registred  isAdmissionComplete  isAdmissionComplete

---

2018-01-23      (null)               No

Comment: Updated with your query and result image.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways, you can check for `null` and replace with some value.

```
IF(<column_name/expr> IS NULL,'NO','YES')
```

**OR**

```
CASE 
    WHEN <column_name/expr> IS NULL
    THEN 'NO'
    ELSE 'YES'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT r.*,
 ifnull(a.isComplete,'No') AS isAdmissionComplete
FROM registration_mt r
left outer join admission_mt a
  on a.registration_id = r.registration_id
WHERE r.schoolyear_yearfrom = 2018;
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized there are no matching `registration_id` in `admission_mt` table which is why I can't get the values. Thanks everyone for your comments and suggestions. I realized that I just had to do a `LEFT JOIN` then apply the `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT r.*,
CASE 
WHEN a.isComplete IS NULL THEN 'No' 
WHEN a.isComplete = 1 THEN 'Yes' END AS isAdmissionComplete
FROM registration_mt r 
LEFT JOIN admission_mt a ON r.registration_id = a.registration_id;
```